# Error 403 (Forbidden) with many file requests

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, java

I am writing a webpage which displays an svg image. A java script should load many small thumbnail images (about 400) in this svg by adding `<image>` tags. As the browsers debugging output shows, not all of these thumbnails are loaded. Many fail with 'Error 403'.

The permissions of the thumbnail files are correct. I can load them individually with the browser. The issue seems to appear consistently with several browsers.

I suspect that I am sending too many simultaneous file requests. I probably cannot have direct access to the server, but it is likely apache2 on linux. Are there parameters that control the maximum number of files per client or hard-coded limits (for instance there is a parameter called `MaxKeepAliveRequests`) or are there any other issues that can cause this behavior?

Is there a way to find the IP of the actual computer running the server (Of course I find the IP that the URL translates into, but as far as I see this computer is not running the actual server. The port might be forwarded)?

Even though this might be off-topic: Is there a recommended java script solution to address such issues when loading many files?

---

I found some apache configuration which could be the relevant one. It seems to load `mod_evasive`. Could this be it?

Relevant configuration is

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
    DOSHashTableSize    3097
    DOSPageCount        10
    DOSSiteCount        50
    DOSPageInterval     1
    DOSSiteInterval     3
    DOSBlockingPeriod   20
    DOSEmailNotify      ""
    DOSLogDir           "/var/log/apache2/mod_evasive.log"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds lime some kind of rate limiting. There are several apache modules that will do that, `mod_qos` being one of them. Usually they will return short body in addition to `403 forbidden` code with little more details, like link to *Acceptable Usage Policy* or similar. See if your scraper script could show you that in addition to 403 error code. There could also be reverse-proxy before apache doing the limiting.

As a solution, keep your number of concurrent request to same site low (if not 1). And obey `robots.txt` ! Also make note of destination site *Terms of Service* and *Acceptable Usage Policy* .

**UPDATE** yes, `mod_evasive` will also do that. You can disable it (if you have control over site) or tune its parameters. Specifically in your case, it will block if you do more than `DOSSiteCount` requests in `DOSSiteInterval` time. So you need to increase allowed number of requests or throttle your fetching speed (by limiting download parallelism and/or inserting delay after each one)

Comment: `mod_qos` is not loaded, but a module called `mod_evasive`. See my edit.

Comment: Ok. I probably won't be able to influence the configuration. So, I guess my only chance is to write some javascript that delays the loading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `evasive` can do that. To verify this, just grep trough Apache's error log files looking for `evasive` and you should get all the info you need.